# How can I give access to a path excluding a sub directory in SVN?

Tags: svn, access-control

Suppose I have projects laid out like this.

- Project_Home

  - A_Project
  - B_Project
  - C_Project
  - D_Project

Can I give a user access to Project_Home and all its subdirectories excluding D_Project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

This work with http access, or, iirc, svnserve with svn > 1.5.

in the access control config, do something like:

```
[repoName:/Project_Home]
user_name=rw
@group_name=rw

[repoName:/Project_Home/D_Project]
user_name=
@group_name=
```